# RGoogleAnalytics Auth function wont open the browser for "Request for Permission"

Tags: r, google-analytics

I'm using the `RGoogleAnalytics` package in a remote Desktop (in a different country), i'm not using my local machine since Google blocks my local machine due to restrictions.

In my local machine, when i run the 'Auth' command:

```
token <- Auth(client.id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              client.secret = "YYYYYYYYYYY")
```

the browser automatically opens a new tab ("Request for permission")  in the browser for me to accept (natural part of authentication) - **This is what should happen**, though when i'm doing it through my remote machine (where i'm logged into the GA account, how it should work), My R console just gets stuck with the following command, without automatically opening a new request for permission tab in the browser:

```
token <- Auth(client.id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              client.secret = "YYYYYYYYYYY")
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
```

Has anyone ran into this issue at the past? I've  actually used this package quit a lot and never ran into this weird issue

Thanks in advance for any help on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by launching a browser remotely :

```
ssh user@server -Y firefox
```

...and launching Rstudio as if it was on localhost.

Just make sure you have a port for Google API authentication response (likely 1410) open for TCP